# I met a woman online

Tags: banking, scams

I talked to her on hangouts and also via texting.
She asked me if I had a bank account and informed her that I don't.
She then says that her uncle is in Mexico would send a check made out in my name and I would deposit it into the bank and send them the account information.
I told them that I'm going to make sure that its legal and if I can get in trouble for cashing a check in my name

Comment: This is 100% a scam. Your best course of action is to stop all contact immediately. And this question is going to get marked duplicate to many other identical scam questions where someone wants to give you money like this.

Comment: If someone gifts you money, fine. If they are sending you money with the expectation that you'll then do something with some/all of the money or give them account access or whatever, it's always a scam or money laundering.

Comment: "and I would deposit it into the bank". What bank would that be, given that you "informed her that (you) **don't**" have a bank account?  Anyway, the others are right: it's 100% a scam.

Comment: If you "meet" anyone, male or female, on-line or in the physical world, who immediately asks you for money-related things, either they're a hooker, or it's a scam.

Comment: @jamesqf They might also be a politician.

Answer (score 6):

Ask yourself: Would you send a check to a random person you met on the internet? Why would you do that? You wouldn't. Unless this was part of some scheme to con the other person out of money.

Now ask yourself: Why would a random person that met you on the internet send you a check? Same reason.

Only ever accept checks from people when you know where they live, if you can knock on their door if the check bounces.

Comment: What's the harm in cashing a cheque? If it bounces you get nothing, but at least you know.

Comment: @Aequitas You believe that somebody would offer you money for no reason ??

Comment: @DumbCoder well it sounded to me like op was having an online relationship with this person. That’s a reason

Comment: @Aequitas - *What's the harm in cashing a cheque?*  Money laundering. If the money goes through an account in the victim's name, to which the criminal has no direct relationship, the criminal gets clean money and the victim is the one who gets their door busted in by the FBI.

Comment: The scam runs this way: 1) They send you a cheque, which you deposit 2) They take the money out of your account 3) the cheque is eventually found to be fake, so the deposit is reversed 4) you now have an account in your name with a negative balance. You owe the bank for that money.

Comment: @Aequitas Cheques don't "bounce" immediately.  It takes time for the system to catch up and reveal the error.  Many people don't know this because the banks will credit you with the amount listed on the cheque (as long as it's not *too big*) immediately - as a convenience to you.  Scammers rely on this to get you to cash a cheque for an amount that's big enough to get your attention but small enough to stay under the cut-off.  The bank will remove the amount they credited you when the cheque turns up fake, but if you've already spent that money, you end up in the hole.